# Efficient map plotting in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, plotly

Using plotly, I've learned to plot maps that represent stuff like 'salary per country' or 'number of XX per country' etc .

Now I'd like to plot the following : say I'm interested in three quantities A,B and C, I would like to plot, for each country, little circles with a size that gets bigger when the value gets bigger, for example :

USA : A=10, B=12,C=3 , I would have 3 circles in the US zone, circle(B)>circle(A)>circle(C).

My dataframe has 4 columns :`columns=['Country','quantity_A','quantity_B','quantity_C']`

How can I plot a map that looks like what I described. I'm willing to use any library that allows that (the simpler the better of course).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Using matplotlib you can draw a scatter plot as follows, where the size of the scatter point is given by the quantity in the respective column.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd

countries = ["USA", "Israel", "Tibet"]
columns=['quantity_A','quantity_B','quantity_C']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(countries),len(columns))+.2,
                  columns=columns, index=countries)

fig, ax=plt.subplots()

for i,c in enumerate(df.columns):
    ax.scatter(df.index, np.ones(len(df))*i, s = df[c]*200, c=range(len(df)), cmap="tab10")

ax.set_yticks(range(len(df.columns)))
ax.set_yticklabels(df.columns) 
ax.margins(0.5) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for your answer, that's actually quite useful and I'll keep it in mind.

But the thing here is that I have more than 50 countries so a scatter plot wouldn't be 'telling much' I think. I would really like to plot a real map, as plotly does, which in this case can be very useful I think.